# Vim not using colorscheme, Gvim does, why?

Tags: vim

I would like to know why my vim is not using my default colorscheme, while gvim does.
Here is what I did:

1. Installed Vim 7.3.
2. Installed Gvim Gtk 7.3
3. Created a folder `~/.vim/colors`
4. Put my "vitamins.vim" file inside of `~/.vim/colors`
5. Created a file called `~/.vimrc`
6. Put the following content in `~/.vimrc`

   ```
   colorscheme vitamins
   set number
   set smartindent
   set tabstop=4
   set shiftwidth=4
   syntax on
   set ignorecase
   set mouse=a
   set hlsearch`
   ```

The problem is that vim doesn't seem to use any of definitions, but Gvim does! Why? 
How can I make a definition file for Vim and another for Gvim? I tried to create a file `~/.gvimrc` but Gvim didn't seem to use anything from that file.

Answer (score 3):

[The vitamins colorscheme](https://github.com/fmoralesc/vim-vitamins/blob/master/colors/vitamins.vim) contains high-color `cterm` definitions. You need a terminal that supports and advertises 256 colors.

```
:set t_Co?
```

must print 256. If it doesn't, you can force this via `:set t_Co=256` (before the `:colorscheme` command), but it's better to choose an appropriate value for `$TERM`, e.g. `gnome-256color`.

Comment: or xterm-256color, type :h term for more help

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use _vimrc instead of .vimrc in windows.

For example, given below is my vim directory structure:

```
C:\Users\pmu\vim>dir
 Volume in drive C is PC COE
 Volume Serial Number is 48FC-5307

 Directory of C:\Users\pmu\vim

04/25/2014  09:00 PM    <DIR>          .
04/25/2014  09:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/28/2014  11:52 PM    <DIR>          vim74
04/15/2014  11:51 PM    <DIR>          vimfiles
04/21/2014  02:06 PM             8,804 _vimrc
              14 File(s)         41,661 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  265,565,655,040 bytes free

C:\Users\pmu\vim>
```

It's better not to use .gvimrc ( or in case of windows _gvimrc) as some plugins might work slowly.

One more thing - I see a ` in there.

```
 set hlsearch`
```

It should be:

```
set hlsearch
```